# Excel VBA code to toggle hide and unhide rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have grouped few rows in my excel sheet. I have added couple of buttons to hide and unhide the rows. But I want to combine the code and have only one button which works more like a toggle button. I am not able to achieve this. These are my individual functions.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels Rowlevels:=1
End Sub
Sub Button2_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels Rowlevels:=2
End Sub
```

Any help with this is appreciated.
Please note: I do not have any experience with VBA and I need this to be done for my maanger's requirement on one of his work.

Thanks

Comment: how do you wish your toggle button to work? When pressed it shows `Rowlevels:1` and hides the other and vise versa?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Activesheet.rows(x & ":" & y).hidden=Not activesheet.rows(x & ":" & y).hidden
```

Where x to y are number of rows you want to hide. For instance:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Rows("2:4").Hidden = Not ActiveSheet.Rows("2:4").Hidden
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried that but does not work -                                                          If Rowlevels = 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels Rowlevels:=2
Else
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels Rowlevels:=1
End If

Comment: I edited my response, check it out to see if it works.